# How to extract data points from the distance matrix using numpy only?

Tags: numpy, knn

I have 2 sets of datapoints:

- **A**: mx10
- **B**: nx10
- Distance matrix **D** of data points in A and B: mxn

How could I extract **k** rows of A using the distance matrix **D**, in which their distances to data points in **B** are smallest? The matrix should have the size of nxk. I do not want to loop through each column and row of the matrix, so I am interested in a way to do this using matrix only.

```
D = np.distance_matrix(A, B)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the full array **D** is already given and "distance to **B**" means "smallest of all the distances to all elements in **B**", then it should be somehting like

```py
d = D.min(axis=1)  # m-long vector of distances from points in A to B
ord = d.argsort()  # an array of indices in d sorted by the corresponding values
kD = d[ord[:k],:]  # take first k elements
```

This is not very efficient if `k` is much smaller than `m`, since it sorts all of the elements instead of just finding `k`th. But it should do the trick.